# NPM execution problem "Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory" in Azure pipeline

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cypress, npx

When I tried to execute
NPM with command **npx cypress run**
it's displaying following error
2022-08-12T07:37:38.5420694Z ##[warning]**Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory**
2022-08-12T07:37:38.5433010Z ##[error]Error: **Npm failed with return code: 1**

[image]

so can anyone please help me with how I can solve this problem
thank you

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of Package.json file? @ksk

Comment: the script in package.json is 
  "scripts": {
    "cy:runit": "npx cypress run"
  },

Comment: @ksk did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description and screenshot, it is shown that the main error message in the screenshot is "Unknown command: "npx" ". It means that the issue will occur when using "npm install" this task to run your pipeline, it is suggested that try using "Command Line" task and adding "npx" in "Script" to test again.

[image]

Comment: i tried with 
command line script as suggested with script 

echo Installing NPX then

echo Hello world

npm install nx

npm audit fix --force

but this step passed but still, the problem persisted at Run Cypress tests with same error message